# Multiple instances of the same UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that the root in a `UINavigationController`. What I'm doing there is I am instantiating another `UIViewController` of the same type, setting some properties and pushing it on top of the stack.

The problem here is that the parent view controller is also changing its property.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
```

Why is this happening? Isn't this creating a new instance of the view controller and copying the same exact properties into a different object instance?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the parent view controller is also changing its property"? What changes when you come back to the parent view controller? And can you indicate where this code snippet lives, I'm assuming within your view controller somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Both view controllers now have a pointer to the same `request` object. Any changes you make are reflected in both controllers. You probably need to copy the `request` object instead, if the controller is able to modify it.

Comment: Oh.. why is that though? Doesn't `alloc init` instantiate a new different object? Or is the default in Objective-C different than C/C++? I tried using `copy` property on `request` and that did not work. How can I copy it then?

Comment: You've only alloc/inited the view controller. That is a different object, but from the limited information in the question, what is displayed in the controller probably depends on the properties of `request`, which you haven't described. If its a custom object, you need to implement copying yourself. See NSCopying protocol for details.

Comment: Yes - I've allocated it from the AppDelegate. And then from within the app itself again as shown above. Doesn't that mean two different objects with separate copies of the same properties? Request holds a `NSURLRequest`. It gets processed in a `UIWebView` within the view controller. Here's the property: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLRequest *request;`. How would I copy that? Using `NSCopying`?

Comment: (nonatomic,copy) but you're losing me a bit. I've added a comment to your question, please answer there by editing your question.